# How to GET background color of a particular portion on the html page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I used Gradient to set the color for my html body background.

**CSS:**

```
background: linear-gradient(to top,  #fb4080 10%,#ebb523 22%,#58d27c 40%,#2aff00 52%,#0fd2b7 65%,#6b6dff 80%,#ff05ea 100%);
```

Now body is filled with multiple colors. Using a javascript how can i get the rgb or hex color code values of a particular portion of the page?

**Example:**

> If i scroll my page, I want to get the color of the top portion of the
>   page(the color inside the highlighted portion not exactly but values near to it) So that i can assign/set that color code to another element on my page like Navigation bar, Menu etc

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: This may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887104/how-to-get-the-background-color-of-an-element-using-javascript

Comment: convert `hsl` to `rgba` with `tinycolor2` - it's what most non-canvas color pickers do

Answer (score 1):

I could think of the following options here:

1. Calculate the gradient in Javascript of which you should be able
   to get the pixel value
   [How to figure out all colors in a gradient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732401/how-to-figure-out-all-colors-in-a-gradient)
2. Create a hidden canvas with the same gradient and pick the pixel
   from this canvas
   http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-linear-gradients/
3. Use a screenshot library for Javascript and pick the pixel from
   the screenshot data.
   [Using HTML5/Canvas/JavaScript to take screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)

Comment: AFAIK, I found 3 is little helpful, But 1 and 2 are explaining how to create a gradient which i already done with it.

Comment: Let me make it more simple to understand, i want the pixel color of any point on the page, Am i clear. Anyway you answer made me think in wide areas I am very thankful to you OSI.

Comment: Then option 3 is the only one suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas and image objects are the only objects you can read pixel values from.

Instead of using a CSS gradient you can create a canvas behind the body of your page and render the gradient into the canvas. After that you can pick a color from the canvas. A complete example is in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60918088/402322) to the question "[How to set an element's background as the same as a specific portion of web page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60914429/402322)".