# Color picker don't know how to add an hex inside of customElements2

Tags: javascript

I am working on a color picker but i dont know how to add the hex value inside the $(customElements2).css

I have a screen
https://image.prntscr.com/image/m52y3J_MQaGlZ_Bi6zc4pw.png

This is not working:

$(customElements2).css('background', 'linear-gradient(rgba(82, 25, 25, 0.45),rgba(249, 55, 55, 0.45),rgb(43, 25, 25)), url(../../../images/netpen/logo-bg.png)');

```
$(customElements2).css('background', 'linear-gradient(rgba(82, 25, 25, 0.45),'hex',rgb(43, 25, 25)), url(../../../images/netpen/logo-bg.png)');
```

Can anyone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

May be something like that, if i understand you right

```
var orientation = 'to right';
var colorOne = '#e65c00';
var colorTwo = '#f9d423';
var el= document.getElementById('customElement2');
el.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient('
    + orientation + ', ' + colorOne + ', ' + colorTwo + ')';
```

Or may be if you have troubles with converting your color to hex check out that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080421/javascript-color-gradient)

---

**UPDATE**

Oh i understand where the problem was, you cannot use image in linear-gradient. Instead you can do what you want like this

```
$(customElements2).css('background-image', 'url(../../../images/netpen/logo-bg.png) linear-gradient(rgba(82, 25, 25, 0.45),'hex',rgb(43, 25, 25))');
```

Comment: i mean i need to replace this: rgba(249, 55, 55, 0.45) to the hex i have tried this  $(customElements2).css("background", "linear-gradient(rgba(82, 25, 25, 0.45),"+ hex +",rgb(43, 25, 25)), url(../../../images/netpen/logo-bg.png)"); but not working

Comment: what inside `hex ` variable?

Comment: You can use `hex` and `rgb` notation in `linear-gradient` property https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZxJLm check out that pan. May be you forgot to place `#` before your `hex` color?

Comment: Yes i know but how do i add the hex varble in this line: $(customElements2).css("background", + "linear-gradient(rgba(82, 25, 25, 0.45),rgba(249, 55, 55, 0.45),rgb(43, 25, 25)), url(../../../images/netpen/logo-bg.png)"); like this    $(customElements2).css("background", + "linear-gradient(rgba(82, 25, 25, 0.45),"+ hex +",rgb(43, 25, 25)), url(../../../images/netpen/logo-bg.png)"); but it is not wotking

Comment: that should work, if not check what inside your `hex` variable                   
 `var hex = '#f9d423';                          
 $(customElements2).css("background", "linear-gradient(rgba(82, 25, 25, 0.45),"+ hex +",rgb(43, 25, 25)), url(../../../images/netpen/logo-bg.png)");`

Comment: Huu i dont understand here is it working 0.o??  `$(customElements).css("background-color", "#" + hex); `but not in the `$(customElements2).css("background", + "linear-gradient(rgba(82, 25, 25, 0.45),"+ hex +",rgb(43, 25, 25)), url(../../../images/netpen/logo-bg.png)"); `

Comment: You forget `+ #`

Comment: No where? i dont understand

Comment: Do you have skype

Comment: Sorry i'm busy right now, try that one `$(customElements2).css("background-image", "url(../../../images/netpen/logo-bg.png) linear-gradient(rgba(82, 25, 25, 0.45), "+ "#" + hex + " ,rgb(43, 25, 25)) ");`